# How do you change default rows per page?

Tags: search-results

I want to change the default from 50 to 100. Where would I do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can in the UI, but you can edit CRM/Utils/Pager.php and change the ROWCOUNT constant near the top.